# Selenium WebDriver 2.20 - IE 8.0 - SeleniumTests.Test.TheTest:System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find Cancel button

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-ide

Following is the code I have wriiten to close the dialog with "Ok/No" button displayed on page load."The web page you are viewing is trying to close the window.Do you want to close this window?" is being displayed. I am able to retrive the alert text but not able to close the alert on click of Ok or No button in I.E.8, only in IE the above message is being displayed.
on accessing the site "http:\172.16.220.24/proof", first proof-sniffer page would get displayed, on closing this page through the alert, proof - sign in page would get displayed.

The exeception on executing the code: 
SeleniumTests.Test.TheTest:System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find Cancel button
is being displayed

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://172.16.220.24/proof/sniffer.aspx");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
IAlert alert=driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
Console.writeline(alert.text);
alert.Dismiss();                      
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

@selenium,@C#

Comment: Just a comment on the Thread.Sleep(1000). You can setup an "driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));" that should allow you to remove those Thread.Sleep(1000); scattered throughout your tests.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in current sources and will be released for general availability in 2.21. You can either wait for the general release, or build the product from sources yourself. Before [this change](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=16305), the IE driver would look for Cancel buttons on alert windows only where the dialog item id was `IDCANCEL` (or 2). This was changed recently so that the driver would look for buttons of either `IDCANCEL` or `IDNO` (or 7).

Comment: TQ for your response. But could you educate me in building the product from source, to try out the same.

Comment: The build process for the Selenium project is documented in the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver). Please note that to build the IE driver native code components, you will need Visual Studio 2010 Professional or higher. The Express edition of Visual C++ will not work.

Comment: The buliding of source did not work out, mozilla-config.h file is missing as well as there was conflict in .Netframework, though I was using Visual studio Professional 10 with framework 3.5. Hence I consuemd the general release 2.21. Thanks